# Python OrderedDict __setitem__ overloading

Tags: python, dictionary, overloading, ordereddictionary

I'm building a class that inherits OrderedDict, in which every key returns a list. I'm looking to overload **setitem** such that if the key doesn't exist, new assignments immediately put the value into a list, otherwise the new value is appended to the list. The following seems to be working:

```
from collections import OrderedDict

class ListDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self):
        super(ListDict, self).__init__()

    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if key in self:
            self[key].append(value)
        else:
            super(ListDict, self).__setitem__(key, [value])

thedict = ListDict()

thedict['a'] = 'first item'
thedict['b'] = 'another first item'
thedict['a'] = 'a second item?'

print thedict
```

which prints:

```
$ python inheritex.py
ListDict([('a', ['first item', 'a second item?']), ('b', ['another first item'])])
```

Instead of appending with an assignment operator '=', I would rather have new items be appended with '+=', or even something like:

```
ListDict['key'] = ListDict['key'] + 'value'
```

How would one go about overloading this? Besides being possible to monkey patch an add function, is it even a Pythonic/readable means to alter class behavior, or is this acceptable because the inherited function (OrderedDict) is untouched?

Comment: FWIW, `if key in self` is _much_ better than `if key in self.keys()` :-)

Comment: @mgilson: Ooof you're right. >.< I still see inheritance code with `self` in it and get woozy and disoriented...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can already use `+=` on *existing* keys:

```
>>> from collections import OrderedDict
>>> thedict = OrderedDict()
>>> thedict['a'] = []  # set initial list
>>> thedict['a'] += ['foo']
>>> thedict['a'] += ['bar']
>>> thedict
OrderedDict([('a', ['foo', 'bar'])])
```

Note that `+=` on a list is basically the same thing as `list.extend()`, so you need to append lists.

If you want this to work for keys that don't exist yet, implement a [`__missing__` method](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__missing__), rather than `__setitem__`:

```
class ListDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = []
        return self[key]
```

When a key is missing during `dict[key]` lookup, `__missing__` is called and it's return value is returned instead of raising a `KeyError`.

Now both `+` and `+=` work on missing keys too:

```
>>> thedict = ListDict()
>>> thedict['a'] += ['foo', 'bar']
>>> thedict['b'] = thedict['b'] + ['spam', 'ham']
>>> thedict
ListDict([('a', ['foo', 'bar']), ('b', ['spam', 'ham'])])
```

If you concatenation must work without adding lists, you could produce a custom list subclass too:

```
class ConcatList(list):
    def __add__(self, value):
        return type(self)(super(ContactList, self).__add__([value]))
    def __iadd__(self, value):
        self.append(value)
        return self
```

then use that type in `__missing__` (and convert any new lists set directly in `__setitem__`):

```
class ListDict(OrderedDict):
    def __missing__(self, key):
        self[key] = ConcatList()
        return self[key]
    def __setitem__(self, key, value):
        if not isinstance(key, ConcatList):
           value = ConcatList([value])
        super(ListDict, self).__setitem__(key, value)
```

after which you can forgo brackets:

```
>>> thedict = ListDict()
>>> thedict['a'] += 'foo'
>>> thedict['b'] = thedict['b'] + 'bar'
>>> thedict
ListDict([('a', ['foo']), ('b', ['bar'])])
```

Comment: I suspect you can also use multiple inheritance to combine `OrderedDict` with `defaultdict` (you'd just need to overload `__init__` to pass `list` as the factory function to the `defaultdict` class).

Comment: @Blckknght: perhaps, but it is so much easier to just go with a custom `__missing__` than to have to figure out how to keep `defaultdict` and `OrderedDict` initialisers happy.

Comment: Yeah, it seems it doesn't actually work due to some kind of conflict (at least in recent versions of Python. I was exploring it for my own answer when I saw yours cover most of the same material.

Comment: @Blckknght: neither has a cooperative `__init__`, so you have to call both explicitly.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `__missing__` seems a lot more elegant than `__setitem__`, although I'm not too keen on requiring list brackets every time someone uses `+=` from a user-input-shell standpoint. Wrapping that in a function should be easy though. Thanks!

Comment: @ultraturtle0: then you'll have to return use custom list subclass that overrides `__iadd__` and `__add__` to handle the concatenation. `class ConcatList(list): def __add__(self, val): return type(self)(self + [val])` for just the `+` case, `def __iadd__(self, val): self.append(val); return self` for the `+=` case.

Comment: In the case where you are using `ConcatList`, wouldn't you _also_ need to override `__setitem__`?  Otherwise, it'd be _really_ easy to make the mistake:  `thedict['a'] = [1, 2, 3]; thedict['a'] += 4` (In other words, it'd be easy to find yourself in a state where your collection held both `list` and `ConcatList`...

Comment: @mgilson: ah, yes, that's a fair point. Overriding `__setitem__` to wrap a list in the new type would evade that issue.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: Just a couple notes: I needed to call `super` with arguments in `ConcatList` to get it to work: `return type(self)(super(ConcatList, self).__add__([value]))`. Also, `ListDict.__missing__()` doesn't seem to initialize a key as a `ConcatList` unless it is added instead of assigned: `thedict['q'] = 'boofar'` results in `('q', 'boofar')`

Comment: @ultraturtle0: right, that's because I assumed Python 3 and you are using Python 2, and the second item is why mgilson suggested using `__setitem__` still.

Answer (score 0):

I've extended [Martijn's](https://stackoverflow.com/users/100297/martijn-pieters) `ListDict` so you can provide `default_factory` and have a similar to [`collections.defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict)'s functionality + key ordering:

```
class OrderedDefaultDict(OrderedDict):
    def __init__(self, default_factory=None):
        self.default_factory = default_factory

    def __missing__(self, key):
        if self.default_factory is None:
            raise KeyError
        self[key] = self.default_factory()
        return self[key]

list_dict = OrderedDefaultDict(list)
list_dict['first'].append(1)
list_dict['second'].append(2)
list_dict['third'].append(3)
assert list(list_dict.keys()) == ['first', 'second', 'third']
assert list(list_dict.values()) == [[1], [2], [3]]

list_dict.move_to_end('first')
assert list(list_dict.keys()) == ['second', 'third', 'first']
```